# ng-blur works fine with ionic serve but does not work when simulating on phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic app that presents a form for the user. For one particular field, I'd like to have it such that the user enters data on the field and an event triggers once the user taps anywhere else.

I went for ng-blur and applied it to the  tag. Testing it on the browser works perfectly well, however when I simulated the app on the phone, tapping anywhere else did not make any difference. What could be the reason?